# How to move last column to nth column?

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

I need to move last column of my text to the nth place ,I tried many variants of awk but not able to maintain the alingment of the file.

#### Below is the replica of the file I am working on:

```
2014-05-27T02:26:46-05:00 nil-severity uuuu vvvvv xxxx yyyy zzzz  
2014-05-27T02:26:22-05:00 nil-severity vvvvv xxxx yyyy zzzz    
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity xxxx yyyy zzzz  
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity yyyy zzzz  
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity vvvvv xxxx yyyy zzzz
```

#### Desired Output:

```
2014-05-27T02:26:46-05:00 nil-severity zzzz uuuu vvvvv xxxx yyyy   
2014-05-27T02:26:22-05:00 nil-severity zzzz vvvvv xxxx yyyy     
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity zzzz xxxx yyyy  
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity zzzz yyyy  
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity zzzz vvvvv xxxx yyyy
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short `awk` command to move the last column to the third:

```
awk '{$3=$NF OFS $3;$NF=""}1' file
```

Comment: You can shorten it by one letter :) `awk '{$3=$NF FS $3;$NF=""}1'` or you can use this short version: `awk '$3=$NF FS$3;$NF=x'`, but its not a god idea setting some to an empty variable, and this can fail of some is `0`

Answer (score 2):

Avoid messing with `FS` manually, just let `awk` do the work for you,

```
awk '{for (i = NF; i >= 3; i--) {$(i+1) = $i}; $3=$NF; NF--}1'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{s = ""; for (i = 3; i < NF; i++) s = s $i FS; print $1, $2, $NF, s}'
```

Comment: Good one. Maybe you can use `s = s $i FS` to make sure it keeps working in case the field separator is changed somewhere else.

Comment: @fedorqui: sure why not, I changed `" "` to `FS`.

Answer (score 0):

With awk

```
awk '{printf $1" "$2" "$NF" "; for (i=3;i<NF;i++) printf $i" "; printf "\n"}' file

2014-05-27T02:26:46-05:00 nil-severity zzzz uuuu vvvvv xxxx yyyy 
2014-05-27T02:26:22-05:00 nil-severity zzzz vvvvv xxxx yyyy 
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity zzzz xxxx yyyy 
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity zzzz yyyy 
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity zzzz vvvvv xxxx yyyy
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this sed command,

```
sed -r 's/^(.*severity) (.*) (.*)$/\1 \3 \2/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat aa

2014-05-27T02:26:46-05:00 nil-severity uuuu vvvvv xxxx yyyy zzzz
2014-05-27T02:26:22-05:00 nil-severity vvvvv xxxx yyyy zzzz
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity xxxx yyyy zzzz
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity yyyy zzzz
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity vvvvv xxxx yyyy zzzz

$ sed -r 's/^(.*severity) (.*) (.*)$/\1 \3 \2/g' aa

2014-05-27T02:26:46-05:00 nil-severity zzzz uuuu vvvvv xxxx yyyy
2014-05-27T02:26:22-05:00 nil-severity zzzz vvvvv xxxx yyyy
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity zzzz xxxx yyyy
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity zzzz yyyy
2014-05-27T02:25:58-05:00 nil-severity zzzz vvvvv xxxx yyyy
```

**Explanation:**

```
sed -r 's/^(.*severity) (.*) (.*)$/\1 \3 \2/g' file
```

`^(.*severity)`  -  Catches all the characters upto the word severity and stored it into a group(1).

- Matches the space that was just after to the word severity.

`(.*) (.*)$` - Fetches all the characters next to the space that was after `severity` upto the last space and stores it to group(2). Atlast the third group contains all the characters that are just after to the last space until the end.

In the replacement part, we just rearranges the captured group according to the desired output.